# C++ + OpenCV = Access violation reading location 0x02176000

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

This code actually used to work until now. I have no idea what is causing it to throw an error now (I don't actually remember making any changes to the code). Here it is (it reads an image from a file to OpenCV IplImage object and then converts it to jpeg buffer):

```
  IplImage* fIplImageHeader = cvLoadImage( filePath.c_str() );

  vector<int> p;
  p.push_back( CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY );
  p.push_back( 75 ); // JPG quality
  vector<unsigned char> buf;
  cv::imencode( ".jpg", fIplImageHeader, buf, p ); // this line gives error
```

The full error is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x638fee22 in Client.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x02176000.
```

The fIplImageHeader contains a valid image which I can confirm by using:

```
cvShowImage( "Window", fIplImageHeader );
```

EDIT:

A longer snippet:

```
while ( l < 30 )
{
            // path to image
    std::stringstream sstm;
    string filePath;
    sstm << workingDirectory << "/temp/" << k << ".jpg";
    filePath = sstm.str();

    cout << filePath.c_str() << endl;

    // load image to IplImage
    IplImage* fIplImageHeader = cvLoadImage( filePath.c_str() );

    // convert to JPG
    vector<int> p;
    p.push_back( CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY );
    p.push_back( 75 ); // JPG quality
    vector<unsigned char> buf;
    cv::imencode( ".jpg", fIplImageHeader, buf, p );

            // do stuff

    k++;
    l++;
    if (10 == k)
    {
        k = 0;
    }

    char key = cvWaitKey( 1000/30 );

    cvReleaseImage( &fIplImageHeader );
}
```

Comment: What does the documentation for `imencode` say about its parameters?

Comment: @Martin York http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Comment: Why are you mixing C++ and C interfaces? (IplImage vs cv::imencode which uses cv::Mat)

Comment: @etarion I think it is the only way to convert IplImage to jpeg without saving it to disk? I can only have it in memory (buffer). If you know another way to do that please post the answer. The point is, though, that the above code used to work.

Comment: The point is, why are you using IplImage* when you have access to the far mor friendly cv::Mat? Also, you should just step through that with a debugger to see what is actually causing the error ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output buffer is supposed to be resized to the output image, but you have not specified an explicit size with the `buf` object.  At least this is mentioned from your referenced doc page at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Can you try setting an explicit size on `buf`?  Right now in your code sample, it is just an empty vector.

EDIT:  Yes, I think you're right, if I squint some more at the doc page, it seems to indicate that `cv::imencode` will do the allocation, so you shouldn't have to.  If that's true then, is your input image really large, are you running out of memory?  Also can you step into the debug version of `cv::imencode`?

EDIT:  There's another code sample at this page http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#Mat

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("greatwave.jpg", 1);
Mat mtx(img); // convert IplImage* -> cv::Mat
```

Can you also try the "convert to cv::Mat" step, and pass that into `cv::imencode`?

Comment: I think vector<unsigned char> is supposed to resize automatically? But I will try setting its size manually. Thanks.

Comment: Image is 31KB jpeg picture. When loaded to IplImage it gets larger, of course. But it should still be pretty small (maybe few hundred KBs).

Comment: I tried the Mat conversion as well. The same exception is thrown. I have added a longer code snippet to my question. I am actually trying to do this in a while loop but the exception is trown during the first cycle so that should not be a problem.

Comment: The conversion is done implicitely, that's why it can work at all works.

Comment: @etarion I also tried just using Mat from the beginning and I get the same exception so there must be a problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT : My bad, I was not using that method... So I don't know what is going wrong...

I had the same exception using "imencode", I don't know if I have to resize the jpegBuf vector

```
void CWebcamWidget::putJpegImage(IplImage *iplImage) {
    // Sans compression jpeg
    //image = QImage((const uchar*)iplImage->imageData, iplImage->width, iplImage->height, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();

    // Still doesn't work using cv::vector...
    cv::vector<int> p;
    p.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
    p.push_back(75); // JPG quality
    cv::vector<uchar> jpegBuf;
    imencode(".jpg", iplImage, jpegBuf, p);

    // Conversion vector<uchar> => uchar*
    uchar *buf;
    memcpy(buf, &jpegBuf[0], sizeof(uchar)*jpegBuf.size());

    image = QImage((const uchar*)buf, iplImage->width, iplImage->height, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
    imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
}
```

I don't know if I really need to convert from vector to uchar*, maybe I can save some CPU time without it...

Answer (score 0):

I also recently encountered this problem in Debug builds of a project using OpenCV 3.0 in conjunction with Visual Studio 2015. The project was previously built with Visual Studio 2013 a while back and I can't remember having this problem. Release builds also didn't trigger the exception. The exception occured during the call to `imencode` which I used like this:

```
bool writeImageToDisk(const std::string& filename, cv::Mat image) {
    std::vector<uchar> imageData;
    bool result = cv::imencode(".jpg", image, imageData);
    if (!result) {
        return false;
    }
    ...
```

I used openvc_world300.dll and .lib which I downloaded from the official OpenCV website. Since they were placed in the subfolder `vc12` I assume they were built with Visual Studio 2013. I couldn't test the Debug version since the appropriate Visual C++ 2013 DLLs were not installed on my system.

After upgrading to OpenCV 3.2 this problem was fixed for me without touching anything else, so maybe there was a bug or a problem with the distributed binaries.