# Stringstream variable does not show in binary code?

Tags: c++, stringstream

why stringstream query variable does not work?

```
std::stringstream query (stringstream::in | stringstream::out | stringstream::binary);


for(vector<uchar>::iterator it=buff.begin();it !=buff.end();it++)
{
    query<<*it;                    
}

cout<<query.str().length();      
printf("output:%s",query);
```

[EDIT]

```
Mat data=image;//image is ROI (50X50) from IplImage* getting Matrix data. 
std::vector<uchar> buff; 
std::vector<int> p; 
p.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION); 
p.push_back(9); 
cv::imencode(".png", data, buff);//for ROI image data to "png" vector buff.  
std::vector<char> query(buff.size()*2+1); //MooingDuck's codes... 
int len = mysql_real_escape_string(handle, &query[0], (const char*)&buff[0], query.size()); 
query.resize(len);
```

I get the error:

> 0040CF5F jmp _escape_string_for_mysql+0F2h (40CFA2h) 0040CF61 mov
>   al,byte ptr [edi] <---------------------------------------error point
>   0040CF63 movsx ecx,al 0040CF66 cmp ecx,5Ch 0040CF69 ja
>   _escape_string_for_mysql+0E5h (40CF95h)

Comment: What's the output? Note that if your chars are non-ASCII codes, the output will be quite garbled. Best to test this with only ascii chars in the buff vector.
Also, you can't printf a stringstream as a %s. query.str().c_str() can be printf'ed though.

Comment: You may want to add a question. We have to guess what you _want_/_expect_ as well as what you _are getting_. Also, what's up with the printf?

Comment: Are you sure it hasn't worked? What are the type and contents of `buff` (the type *should* be `vector<uchar>` to match the iterator, but...)? If you just want the contents of `buf` in a string, why not just use a string directly instead of using a stringstream?

Comment: **bold** Thank you very much, you are right, main issue is buff vector has png (graphic data). I will pass to mysql blob data type. How could it send?

Comment: buf is not string "png" or "jpg" type binary code.

Comment: thank you for your answer jerry.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using `printf` wrong. It's best not to use `printf` at all.

```
std::cout << query.str();
```

Also, specifying `binary` here is pretty much useless, and `in`/`out` are superfluous (`stringstream` is by default in/out).

Comment: Hi,thank you very much, we need to pass "query" varible also has binary code to pass mysql blob type, well ask for it.

Comment: @Tansistem: Sorry, I can't understand you.

Comment: Also,thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`stringstream::binary` does not do what you think it does.

`stringstream::binary` makes the stream not translate system newlines as a C++ newlines.  `stringstream::text` makes streams transalte system newlines into C++ newlines.
Neither of which makes streams read or write as "binary code".

A C++ newline is `\n`, whereas a Windows system newline is `\r\n` (two characters!), and linux uses just `\n`.  I've heard that Mac system newlines are/were `\n\r` but I can't confirm that.

Also, as [Oli Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8319173/845092) and [Cat Plus Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8319172/845092) observed, `printf` does not work with C++ objects.  Use `std::cout` instead, or convert the `std::string` into a `const char*` that `printf` understands.

Judging by your comment, you want something along the lines of

```
std::vector<char> query(buff.size()*2+1);
int len =  mysql_real_escape_string(mysql, &query[0], (const char*)&buff[0], query.size());
query.resize(len);
```

This will escape binary data in `buff` for safe insertion into a mysql query.

Comment: You are great, the main issue is buff vector has "png" type binary data. I want to pass mysql blob type column record. I know mysql_real_escape but, I search day by day did not find solution!!!

Comment: @Tansistem: did I address the real question then?

Comment: Great Mooing Duck. Build code OK!.But giving runtime error!in my opinion buff vector is uchar.   
   Mat data=image;
    std::vector<uchar> buff;

    std::vector<int> p;
    p.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    p.push_back(9);

    cv::imencode(".png", data, buff);

Comment: Please update the question with the full information.  The code you posted does not contain `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Hi Mooing Duck. It is getting runtime error. Sory for english lang.

  

    Mat data=image;//image is ROI (50X50) from IplImage* getting Matrix data.  

    std::vector<uchar> buff;

    std::vector<int> p;
    p.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    p.push_back(9);

    cv::imencode(".png", data, buff);//for ROI image data to "png" vector buff.


    std::vector<char> query(buff.size()*2+1); //your codes...



 int len =  mysql_real_escape_string(handle, &query[0], (const char*)&buff[0], query.size());
 
 
 query.resize(len);

Comment: @Tansistem: I put the code in the question for you.  What is the full text of the runtime error, and on what line does it occur?

Comment: Hi,Mooing,i think mysql function pointer problem???

Comment: 0040CF5F jmp _escape_string_for_mysql+0F2h (40CFA2h) 
0040CF61 mov al,byte ptr [edi] <---------------------------------------error point
0040CF63 movsx ecx,al 
0040CF66 cmp ecx,5Ch 
0040CF69 ja _escape_string_for_mysql+0E5h (40CF95h)

Comment: somethink similar:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474076/c-opencv-access-violation-reading-location-0x02176000